# route all spam to a specific account with amavisd-new and SpamAssassin

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis

I've just set up an MTA using postfix, amavisd-new and SpamAssassin (and ClamAV but not relevant for this question). This MTA sits in front of our mail server and handles scanning of mail for spam and viruses prior to delivery on to our actual mail server. (basically a "backup MX server" model)

The scanning of mail is working fine and mail is being delivered properly however I'd like to make a change to this MTA so that anything that is marked by amavisd/SA as likely spam (tag2) is routed to a central mail box (spam@mydomin.com) rather than being delivered with an updated subject line (which still fills up user inboxes) or holding for quarantine (which isn't accessible as this MTA is separate to the main server).

I found documentation on doing [plus-addressing](https://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/amavisd-new-docs.html#addrext) but this doesn't suit my needs as I want it to go to a separate mailbox rather than a plus-addressed version of the same box.

Answer (score 0):

not the specific answer you're looking for but perhaps worth considering is this.  I route all SPAM to each individual user's Junk folder using a sieve script.  Then on a periodic basis, scan the Junk folders to improve the SPAM heuristics.  In theory, you could have a global sieve script that delivers another copy (or perhaps the only copy) to a mailbox not belonging to a user that might serve your purpose.